# Java with XPath and TagSoup

Tags: java, xpath, tag-soup

I am using TagSoup with java to extract some data , but certain XPATH are not working , I just get empty results

```
  FileReader frInHtml = new FileReader("doc.html");
  BufferedReader brInHtml = new BufferedReader(frInHtml);

  SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
   org.jdom.Document jdomDocument = saxBuilder.build(brInHtml);

 // This is working                                
 XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/ns:html[1]/ns:body/ns:div[@class='content']/ns:table/ns:tr/ns:td/ns:h1");

// All 3 lines below didn't work , tried them 1 at a time 
  XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/ns:html/ns:body/ns:div[7]/ns:table/ns:tbody/ns:tr/ns:td/ns:h1");
  XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("//html//body//div[7]//table//tbody//tr//td//h1");
  XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td/h1");                               

   xpath.addNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

Comment: Hard to say without the XML. I noticed that in the one which work you don't use `tbody` tag whereas it's always present in the 3 others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this you will need to look at the "equivalent XML" produced by TagSoup. And for us to help you, you will need to show us the equivalent XML.